# This program isn't asking for the predetermined 5 numbers from the array?

Tags: c++

Okay, so this question is difficult to state.

I'm a beginner at C++, and I rarely run into problems with these simple assignments, but something is majorly wrong here and I cannot identify it. I've been trying for hours.

This program is supposed to read 5 numbers from an array that the user enters, and then print the largest one. 
(I know it's easier to just write a for-loop, but our professor wanted us to call a function).

The only problem is that instead of asking for 5 numbers, it asks for 2. It works other than that, I JUST NEED IT TO ASK FOR 5 NUMBERS. haha.

Your input would be greatly appreciated. I aspire to be a programmer one day, so don't be afraid to go harsh on me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int largest_number(int score[], int max)
{ 
    for (int i=1; i<5; i++)
    {
        cin >> score[i];
        if(score[i] > max)
            max=score[i];

        return (max);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int score[5], max, z;

    cout << "Enter 5 numbers: " <<endl;
    cin >> score[0];
    max = score[0];

    z = largest_number(score, max);

    cout << "The largest number is: " << z <<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to store the array? Which function should read in the numbers?

Comment: On error is that your return statement is inside of the for loop.  So it goes into the loops and returns, not getting to the next iteration through the loop.  Move the return outside of the for loop scope and it should then work.

Comment: You would probably do best to separate the input from finding the maximum.  You should have one loop to read 5 values into `score[0]` to `score[4]`.  You then have a function `int maximum(int *values, int num_values) { ... }` which iterates over the array and returns the maximum value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int largest_number(int score[], int max)
{ 
    for (int i=1; i<5; i++)
    {
        cin >> score[i];
        if(score[i] > max)
            max=score[i];

        return (max); //whoops! it's inside the for loop
    }
}
```

- You made a mistake by putting your return inside of the for loop,
  this means no matter what you're only entering `score[1]` because the function will return max afterwards.

Remove the return inside your for loop and put it at the end of the function, and you should be fine.

Comment: But OP is also using `cin` in `main()`.

Comment: which is why he is only prompted for two numbers, one in main and one from the function(not 4 from the function)

Comment: Oh. My. God.

I have been working on the logic of this program for 3 hours, and I accidentally put my return INSIDE THE LOOP?!?!

hahaha. Practice makes perfect.

Good eye. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it. <3

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the quick and detailed answers. I absolutely love this community. Need4Sleep fixed the problem. My return was inside the for loop in the function definition....
I fixed that, tested several different integers, and it worked.
The smallest mistake cost me hours.
Thanks again. <3333

Comment: Glad to see someone so enthusiastic about the community, best of luck programming.

Comment: That's twice this website has saved me from losing my 100 average in my beginner C++ class, due to stupid errors.
Naturally, I am immensely grateful. Thanks man, same to you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate flies from meatballs as we say here.
Good choice is to make function that only find max and to fill array separately.

Example:

```
    int FindMax(int score[], int size)
    {
       int max = score[0];
       for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
           if(score[i] > max)
              max = score[i];
       return max; 
    }

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 5;
    int score[SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter " << i << " number\n";
        cin >> score[i];
    }

    cout << "\nMax is " << FindMax(score, SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would it not be best to pass the number of scores to your `FindMax()` function?  The separation of input from maximum finding is certainly correct separation of duty.

Answer (score 2):

in your for loop

```
for (int i=1; i<5; i++)
{
    cin >> score[i];
    if(score[i] > max)
        max=score[i];

    return (max);
}
```

you return.  when you write that return statement, the function exits, and you don't go through the rest of the loop.

I think you meant to put the return statement outside the loop

```
for (int i=1; i<5; i++)
{
    cin >> score[i];
    if(score[i] > max)
        max=score[i];
}
return (max);
```

also, `Fomin Arseniy`, had a good point(though not gracefully stated).

You should collect your input in one step, and then find the largest number in the next step.  For problems as simple as this, it doesn't make too much of a difference, but it's a pattern you should learn for harder problems.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the wonderful world of code!

1. Remember that when return is called, it breaks out of the for loop and goes back to the caller. With that said, within your **largest_number** function, simply pull the return statement...

   ```
   return (max);
   ```

   ...out of the for loop
2. Begin your for loop by initializing your variable **i** to 0, and not 1. That way you will get 5 cycles, rather than 4.
3. Ensure that the first time the for loop executes, the **max** variable gets set to whatever is entered. I'm making sure this happens by using the following condition in the if statement

   `score[i] > max || i == 0`

   Notice the **i == 0**. Think about why that works.
4. Your **largest_number** function does not need to be passed the parameter **max**. You can simply create a local variable called **max** within your function and use that.
5. Also, try to name your functions using the 'Camel Hump' format (example below).

Your final (working) function will look like this:

```
int largestNumber(int score[])
{ 
   int max = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      cin >> score[i];
      if (score[i] > max || i == 0)
        max = score[i];
   }
   return (max);
}
```